# Glassfish 2.x EJB library missing

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I have a web-app running smoothly on GlassFish 3.1.2 which is on my local machine. However I get to put this app on an actual server which runs GF2.1.

When I tried to import the netbeans project into the netbeans (which is a lower version) and compiled it, few of my import library get "class not found“ error.

Below are those imports:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

Just wondering how could I possibly solve this?

Is there any chance that I can add some more library manually onto Glassfish 2.1?

Or is there any alternatives approach that I can go for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using items defined in EJB 3 (javax.ejb.Startup, for example).  EJB 3 is not supported by Glassfish 2.

You've written your application against the JavaEE 6 specifications (which is supported by Glassfish 3).  So the best bet is to run it in a container which supports it.  Glassfish 2.x supports JavaEE 5, not 6.  I don't think you'll be able to run it as is in Glassfish 2

Comment: Hi Ed, you are correct, im using JavaEE 6. Could you please share more about using a container? I'm a newbie for JavaEE, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are using JavaEE 6, but the actual server into which you are deploying is not.  Glassfish 2 does not support JavaEE 6.  It is my understanding that if you want JavaEE 6 on a Glassfish server you need a version 3.x of Glassfish.